# How to merge 3 javascript object with modified value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have 3 objects like 
[

```js
const arr = [
{name:'ABC', value:123},
{name:'ABC', value:456},
{name:'ABC',value:789},
{name:'DEF',value:9999},
name:'DEF', value:0000}
]
```

i want output like

```js
updatedArr = [
  {name:'ABC', value:123, value1:456, value2:789}
  {name:'DEF', value:9999, value1:0000}
]
```

any kind of links regarding this will be also helpful.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: Strongly recommend **not** having varying property names as in the output. Instead, consider an array: `{name: "ABC", values: [123, 456, 789]}`.

Comment: Also, why can't you use `{ "ABC": 123 }` instead of `{name: "ABC", value: 123}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method to create an object and then `Object.values` to get an array of values.

```js
const arr = [{name:'ABC', value:123},{name:'ABC', value:456},{name:'ABC',value:789},{name:'DEF',value:9999},{name:'DEF', value:0000}]

const res = arr.reduce((r, e) => {
  if(!r[e.name]) r[e.name] = {...e}
  else {
    let {name, ...rest} = r[e.name];
    r[e.name][`value${Object.keys(rest).length}`] = e.value
  }
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'ABC',
    value: 123
  },
  {
    name: 'ABC',
    value: 456
  },
  {
    name: 'ABC',
    value: 789
  },
  {
    name: 'DEF',
    value: 9999
  },
  {
    name: 'DEF',
    value: 0000
  }
]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.name]) {
    acc[item.name] = item;
  } else {
    acc[item.name]['value' + (Object.keys(acc[item.name]).length - 1)] = item.value;
  }

  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -2):

use object assignation:

```
Object.assign(ob1,ob2);
```